# how to get the locations of keyboard shortcut set for shortcut files

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I have created keyboard shortcuts for many shortcut files.

[image]

Now I don't know for which shortcut file I have created a shortcut.
I want to know all the shortcut files for which I have created the shortcuts, so that I can delete some of them.
**Is there a way by which I can know all the shortcut files for which keyboard shortcut has been set.**

Comment: Interesting. I'd expect something like this has to be in the Registry somewhere. Otherwise, enumerating all .lnk files and checking the Shortcut Key details on them would be... interesting, to say the least. BTW: The current version of Reader is 11.0.09. You should probably update.

Comment: I tried to search value of some lnk or program files whose shortcut I have created. but found nothing. @Iszi

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Ethervane ActiveHotkeys](http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=18189.msg162881) , a freeware will collect all the shortcut keys assigned in the machine. Please take a look at the above link and check out your results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The software you suggested does not provide the information about the file in windows. But thanks for helping me `+1`